# how to not display arrow in HTML <details> without using CSS on Safari browser

Tags: html, web

I'am building my homepage on webpage building platform such as Wix, Wordpress. But my platform does not support importing css files...
I used 'details' tag on my homepage. But I found that it doesn't showing arrow on a chrome browser but on safari browser it shows arraow.
I want to hide arrows on safari too.

So I tried this code.

```
<details style="list-style:none;">
   <summary style="list-style:none;font-size:14px; cursor:pointer;">Open</summary>
</details>
```

I put 'list-style:none;' but it still doesn't working.
So is there some way to not display arrows without using cssfile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't target pseudo-classes or pseudo-elements in inline style, so the only option if you still want to write it in HTML file would be like so:

```
<style>
   summary::-webkit-details-marker {
      display:none;
   }
</style>
```

Comment: No effect on my Safari browser.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, the answer is very simple, but not intuitive.

---

use `display: block;` in **summary**

```css
summary {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>hello world</summary>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque quos exercitationem quis delectus. Nisi, porro! Possimus placeat quasi aliquid, aperiam ex, adipisci fugiat similique, minima autem assumenda quod quis officiis!</p>
</details>
```

you can use the same method you see above, with `style="display: block;"` if your CMS doesn't support importing `.css` *files*

is only one CSS property, so you can. (this is the easiest solution for now)

---

---

**OR** I see now on the internet, there you can style this *pseudo-element* `::-webkit-details-marker`

> everything starts with 2colons **::** like this *::NameOfPsudoElement* is pseudo-element)

```css
::-webkit-details-marker {   
   display:none; 
}
```

but I don't think your CMS will support uploading external `.css` file because you can't use the `style=""` method for the *pseudo-elements*

but if your cms support writing your own HTML,

 you can nest the CSS above inside the `<style>` tag

---

So for me go for the first answer!

```css
summary {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>hello world</summary>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque quos exercitationem quis delectus. Nisi, porro! Possimus placeat quasi aliquid, aperiam ex, adipisci fugiat similique, minima autem assumenda quod quis officiis!</p>
</details>
```

Comment: Neither setting the summary to display:block, nor setting webkit details marker to display:none, has any effect for my Safari browser.